# Como cambiar el alto de un navbar de boostrap

Tags: responsive, navbar

Estoy utilizando el navbar predeterminado de BOOSTRAP pero es muy alto y necesito que sea mas pequeño. Cuando trato de forzarlo en un CSS con height lo consigo pero luego el modo responsive no funciona...

¿Alguien sabe como cambiar el tamaño del navbar predeterminado de boostrap?

Comment: Hola si no pones un ejemplo, dificilmente te vamos a ayudar.

Comment: @SAGEX por favor sé educado. Lo que dice Andrés es correcto. Sin tu código no es fácil indicar una solución apropiada.

Comment: Agrega como fue que lo intentaste, para ver porque se rompe el responsive.